# Setting a variable of findstr result

Tags: batch-file

I have a bat file that has the following code in it. It writes the content to the text file beautifully how ever i am going to expand this script a bit and im needing to set variables for the findstr result.

I have tried the following options with no luck

Here is how i have tried it so far

```
`
systeminfo | set hostnme = findstr /c:"Host Name">>string.txt
systeminfo | findstr set dimain =  /c:"Domain">>string.txt 
set osnme =  systeminfo | findstr /c:"OS Name">>string.txt 

`
```

I know im probably missing something super simple but through some googling and little background i have with batch files im having trouble finding it.

Here is my whole code.

```
`
@echo on
echo Checking your system infor, Please wating... 
systeminfo | findstr /c:"Host Name">>string.txt
systeminfo | findstr /c:"Domain">>string.txt 
systeminfo | findstr /c:"OS Name">>string.txt 
systeminfo | findstr /c:"OS Version">>string.txt 
systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Manufacturer">>string.txt 
systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Model">>string.txt 
systeminfo | findstr /c:"System type">>string.txt 
systeminfo | findstr /c:"Total Physical Memory">>string.txt 
ipconfig | findstr IPv4>>string.txt
echo %hoo%
echo.

echo Hard Drive Space: 
wmic diskdrive get size>>string.txt

echo. 
echo.

echo Service Tag: 
wmic bios get serialnumber>>string.txt

echo. 
echo. 
echo CPU: 
wmic cpu get name>>string.txt

echo Completed! Thank you!
echo %ComputerName%

rename "string.txt" "%ComputerName%.txt"
echo Rename Completed! 
start "" http://www.localhost.com?txt=%ComputerName%

pause
`
```

I would like to our put each result of the following items as variables so i can use them elsewhere in the code

```
systeminfo | findstr /c:"Host Name">>string.txt
systeminfo | findstr /c:"Domain">>string.txt 
systeminfo | findstr /c:"OS Name">>string.txt 
systeminfo | findstr /c:"OS Version">>string.txt 
systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Manufacturer">>string.txt 
systeminfo | findstr /c:"System Model">>string.txt 
systeminfo | findstr /c:"System type">>string.txt 
systeminfo | findstr /c:"Total Physical Memory">>string.txt 
ipconfig | findstr IPv4>>string.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('systeminfo 2^>nul') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=*" %%r IN ("%%b") DO (
  IF /i "%%a"=="System Manufacturer" SET "#sys_man=%%r"
  IF /i "%%a"=="Host Name" SET "#hostname=%%r"
  IF /i "%%a"=="OS Version" SET "#osversion=%%r"
 )
)

ECHO ------------------- results
SET #
GOTO :eof
```

The `2^>nul` disposes of the progress messages. `2>nul` is redirecting stderr to nul, the caret tells `cmd` the `>` is part of  the command too be executed, not of the `for`.

The `"tokens=1*` splits each line on the `delims` character, so that part before the colon is assigned to `%%a` and the remainder of the line to `%%b`.

The inner `for` uses `tokens=*` to dispose of the leading spaces in `%%b` (space is included in the default delimiter set)

Then detect each required string and assign to a variable. I simply prefixed each variable I used with `#` so I coulod use `set #` to display them all and no variables starting `#` are assigned by the system.

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified what is the contents of `string.txt` file. You have requested to store the result of `findstr` commands *in variables*.

The standard way to get the output of any command and assign it to a variable is this:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('anyCommand with parameters') do set "variable=%%a"
```

For example, in your case:

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('systeminfo ^| findstr /C:"Host Name"') do (
   for /F "tokens=*" %%b in ("%%a") do set "hostname=%%b"
)
```

The first `for /F` command get the part of the output line after the colon. The second `for /F` eliminate the leading spaces in this part, and the `set` command assign the result to `hostname` variable.

An inconvenient in your code is that `systeminfo` is an expensive command that takes too long to complete, so using it to extract *just one line* and then repeat this command for the next line is a waste of resources... A better approach is run `systeminfo` just one time and then extract *all desired lines* from it.

An even better approach is *not* test for each desired line/variable in a series of `if` commands in order to individually define each of them, but just define variables *for all lines* instead. To do that, you may create the *name* of the variables from the description before the colon in each line.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo Please wait . . .
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('systeminfo 2^>nul') do (
   set "varName=%%a"
   if "!varName:~0,1!" neq " " (
      for /F "tokens=*" %%c in ("%%b") do set "#!varName: =_!=%%c"
   )
)

set #
```